# Can I replace all the instances of a string in a CSV file before loading it in a spark df?

Tags: dataframe, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a CSV file of around 35gb that contains data in the mentioned format.

```
"Col1"^A"Col2"^A"Col3"^A"Col4"
"1"^A"AB\\"CD"^A"0000"^A"0000"
"2"^A"AB\\"CD\\"^A"0000"^A"0000"
```

Where we have `^A` separator

Now the issue is that when I load it in a spark df, using:

```
df=spark.read.csv(file_path, sep="^A", header=True, multiLine=True)
```

The output is something like this:

```
"1"|"AB\"CD"|"0000"|"0000"
"2"|"AB\"CD"^A"0000"|"0000"|undefined
```

And if I try to solve it using the escape option `escape="\\""`,
The entire df goes haywire and data of all the columns are stored in one row where `\` appears and makes multiLine option irrelevant as well.

I can't change it using regex after creating df as the columns in df would already be distorted.

Is there any way in which I can  get past this `\\` breaking the df issue without messing with multiLine option? If not, is there any way I can replace all instances of `\\"` with `"` in the entire CSV file through pyspark and then create df?

Thanks in advance!

Have tried using `escape="\\""` and `quote="}"`, they do solve the column issue in some cases but end up messing the multiLine entries. Please let me know if any other inputs are required. Thanks.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I expect both the rows to be same even if the data has \ in the end of a cell. But in the second case, it's not recognising the separator that comes right after it. So ideally                       "1"|"AB"CD"|"0000"|"0000" or  "2"|"AB"CD\"|"0000"|"0000" works for me.

Comment: Is your input file containd space between "col4" and "1" or it should be in separate line?

Comment: It's in a new line(crlf). But there are some rows for which the data contains a newline(enter) so newLine=True is required for them to keep them in the same row in df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i got same results in my environment.

[image]

You follow all these ways.
Below is the data in csv file.

[image]

In my case escape `\"` worked successfully.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/todaytst.csv", sep="^A", header=True, multiLine=True,escape='\"')
df = df.select([regexp_replace("Col1",'\\\\','').alias('Col1'),regexp_replace("Col2",'\\\\','').alias('Col2'),regexp_replace("Col3",'\\\\','').alias('Col3'),regexp_replace("Col4",'\\\\','').alias('Col4')])
display(df)
```

[image]

If it doesn't work, try with escape `'"'` in the above code.

Even that does not work, replace them initially and load into spark dataframe.

You can use below function to replace the things and write into new file.

```
file_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/todaytst.csv"
output_file_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/modtmp.csv"
with  open(file_path,  "r")  as infile:
    with  open(output_file_path,  "w")  as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            replaced_line = line.replace('\\"',  '"')
            outfile.write(replaced_line)
```

And read the new file.

```
spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/modtmp.csv", sep="^A", header=True, multiLine=True)
```

[image]

Or you replace all `\` and `"` to empty and read them.

```
file_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/todaytst.csv"
output_file_path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/modtmp.csv"
with  open(file_path,  "r")  as infile:
    with  open(output_file_path,  "w")  as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            replaced_line = line.replace('\\',  '')
            replaced_line = replaced_line.replace('"',  '')
            outfile.write(replaced_line)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jayashankar, thanks for your detailed solution, I have tried escaping / and " but it's not working for me as there are some issues with nextLine as well further in the data but replacing it in data before converting to df seems like a nice option to me, but I'm using synapse notebook and the CSV file is in adls, open(file_path, 'r') isn't working there, any idea how I can get past that? Thanks again for all your help till now, means a lot.

Comment: ok. Did you mounted that adls in synapse.

Comment: Ohh, apologies, done it and it's working now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NaveenSharma, done, thanks for the reminder. Thanks again JayashankarGS.